# how do I find a region bounded by a curve, the line y = 11x and the y axis?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The full question : 
A curve has equation $y = 10 + 8x + x^2 - x^3,\; x \geq 0$

a)Find the coordinates of the turning point. and show whether it is maximum or minimum.

b) Hence, Find the area of the region bounded by the curve, the line y = 11x and the y axis?

I manage to complete a) which I got :

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 8 + 2x - 3x^2$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

$(-3x^2 + 2x + 8) = 0$

$\begin{align}
3x^2 - 2x -8 &= (3x + 4) ( x - 2)\\
&= 0
\end{align}
$

So
$x = -4/3$ or $x = 2$

since $x \geq 0$ I chose $2$

$x = 2$

$y = 10 + 8(2) + (2)^2 - (2)^3$

$y = 22$

so turning point is $(2, 22)$

//finding max or min :

$f(-4/3) = 10 + 8(-4/3) + (-4/3)^2 - (-4/3)^3
= -50/27$

$f(-4/3) < 0$ $\therefore$ maximum

$f(2) = 10 + 8(2) + (2)^2 + (2)^3
=22$

$f(2) > 0$ $\therefore$ minimum

The part I am stuck is part b) I don't quite sure how to solve it.Please can you help me with this part? Thank you !

Comment: Just to check do you mean bounded by the $x$ axis or $y$ axis? Often these kind of questions use the $x$ axis but worth checking :)

Comment: Also, there is an error when finding the max/min - first we don't need to worry about $-\frac{4}{3}$ as it's not in the domain. Secondly the point at 2 is a maximum. You need to use the first or second derivative test; work out $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and then see if result is positive or negative

Comment: @Dan90 To be honest, I'm not sure if it's bounded by x or y. The question wrote: " Find the area of the region bounded by curve, the line y = 11x and the y axis (x = 0)" may be it's bounded by y?

Answer (score 1):

[image: cubic graph and y=11x]

The line intersects the graph at the maximum of the cubic, since the coordinate $(2,22)$ lies on $y=11x$.

What we need to calculate is the area between two curves which is

$$
\int_a^b (y_1 - y_2)\; dx
$$

Where $y_1$ is the cubic curve and $y_2$ is the lower curve (the line). So we have

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^2 (10 + 8x + x^2 - x^3 -11x)\; dx &=
\int_0^2 (10 - 3x + x^2 - x^3)\; dx \\
&= \left[ 10x - \frac{3}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x^4\right]_0^2 \\
&=\frac{38}{3}
\end{align}
$$

What we have calculated is the region above the blue line, right of the $y$-axis and below the red (like an obtuse triangle, but the red line of course is not straight).

You may have also approached this by calculating the area under the red curve and then subtracting the area made by the triangle formed by the blue line and the line $x=2$ (anything further to the right would not be within the constraints defined by the question), but both methods are essentially the same (subtracting the area of the triangle is the $-y_2$ bit in the integral)